# Change color of a black & white PNG?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors

I have a PNG that's black and white (specifically, from http://modernuiicons.com/) - I'd like to change its color in part of my diagram. I'm currently working in Word. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it - Format Picture -> Picture Color -> Recolor.